# TypeError: Cannot read property 'eslint' of undefined

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, koa2

I have this problem when I used nuxt-community/koa-template in github, I have already used such instructions as "NPM install",but problem still remain. Please give me some solutions.

Comment: Please describe you problem with more details. Such as your operatis system, npm version, package.json contents, what command produce that error, etc etc

Answer (score 1):

It is because of old eslint loader that dont work with newest nuxt.

Dont use nuxt-community/koa-template, use create-nuxt-app https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app . It have a koa as an option and it wont have this problem